# WhatsApp showing different value for used storage on app info and in-app settings

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, internal-storage, storage, insufficient-memory

In my Samsung Galaxy S9, WhatsApp is showing that it uses 37.89GB of internal storage when I checked the app info.

[image]

Due to that, my phone's data is getting full and all the other apps are getting hung due to less storage space left in my mobile phone.

When I checked the WhatsApp 'Settings' -> 'Data and storage usage' it shows only 195.1MB of data has been stored for WhatsApp.

[image]

From where the 37.89GB of data is being shown in the app info on my phone?

**Please note:** I don't want to delete my WhatsApp and reinstall it to fix this issue because I don't want to lose my WhatsApp messages, and I can't take the backup also because there is no more space left on my mobile to take the backup.

Answer (score 0):

The storage usage which you saw in the device settings page (App info), includes cached data too. Click on the **Storage** in the **App info** page of WhatsApp. There you will find a **Clear cache** button. Click on that.

[image]

[image]

**Side note:** WhatsApp's data storage information only shows the storage usage by multimedia and messages. Besides those things, WhatsApp also stores its settings, multimedia that you have shared with others, and downloaded statuses. So, you cannot rely much on the information which is shown as **Storage usage** in WhatsApp. If you want to know more about the real storage usage, open up a file manager and browse the **WhatsApp** folder inside the primary storage. See these screenshots and note the differences (114 MB vs 12 MB):

[image]

[image]

Comment: I cleared the cache and but still it dosent helped me because it still shows that I have 37.84Gb and in total **37.89GB**, please check this link for the screenshot [link](https://ibb.co/hyTDK6D) but when I checked the whatsapp 'settings' -> 'Data and storage usage' it shows only 195.1MB of data has been stored for whatsapp. I am super confused from where does this data(37.89GB) is being stored

I deleted all the sent items(docs, images, voice messages and all) still the issue remains sae

Comment: Look into the WhatsApp folder in the device's storage. Look for hidden files too. See whether there is any file taking up a lot of space.

Comment: Cleared all the hidden files from WhatsApp folder in the device's storage but in those hidden folder all the data comined together was like ~2MB only. Still I cant find the 37.89GB